# how to fill color for a region based on value in mapbox?

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

i am using [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com) that draws zip-code outline based on the external `geojson` file as shown below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mapbox',
  templateUrl: './mapbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mapbox.component.css']
})
export class MapboxComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'api-key';
    let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'styles',
      zoom: 5,
      center: [-80.118, 25.897]
    });

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

    map.on('load', function () {
      map.addSource("route", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": "./assets/shapeGeoJson.json"
      });

      map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "route",
        "paint": {
          'line-color': "gray"
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

here, am able to load the `geojson` in which i will get the outline of the zipcodes.

Now, i want to call a api where in will get the `density` count for zipcodes and i need to paint the zipcode layer based on the `density` value.

Can any one tell me how to achieve this?

any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [addSource](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addsource) of Mapbox. Just add these line in your code

```
map.addSource('zipDensity', {
          type: 'geojson',
          data: {
            ...geoJsonObj // this can be your data from API containing density prop
          } 
});

map.addLayer({
          'id': 'zipDensity',
          'source': 'zipDensity',
          'type': 'fill',
          'paint': {
            'fill-color': {
              property: 'density', // this will be your density property form you geojson
              stops: [
                [1000, '#CECECE'],
                [100000, '#DEDEDE'],
              ]
            },
            'fill-opacity': 1
          }
});
```

In `addLayer` you can add stops where you can add density value and color code. You can explore more props of `addLayer`

Hope It helps for you..